# how to assign value inside {{input}} helper rather than creating a binding?

Tags: html, ember.js, ember-data

In my input helper,

```
{{input type="text" value=model.name  enter=(action (action 
'sampleFunction' model))}}
```

When I change the value in the form, i want to send the value alone to the action. But, model.name is also getting changed.

What should I do such that only "value" changes and model doesn't change?

Answer (score 4):

The answer is somewhat dependent on your Ember version. If you are Ember >= 2.3.1, then I would recommend using the `<input>` natively:

```
<input value={{password}} oninput={{action 'setPassword' value="target.value"}} />
```

With an action:

```
actions: {
  setPassword(val){
    if(/* only update on some condition */){
        this.set('password', val);
    }
    this.updatePasswordsMatch2();
  }
}
```

`value` is what's rendered, and the argument of the action is whatever is in the field + last typed char.

If you are Ember 1.13x <=> 2.3.0, then have a look at [Ember One way controls](https://github.com/DockYard/ember-one-way-controls) which leveraged glimmer's ability to use `<input>` directly. You will need to use the library since there is a workaround some cursor jumping that wasn't ironed out until 2.3.1.

If you are <1.13x, upgrade? If you are actually are, comment back and I'll try to think of something

Answer (score 1):

Ember has two-way-binding system. You can use Ember's `readonly` helper to assign a value to the component as one-way binding like this:

```
value=(readonly model.name)
```

You can take a look at [this twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/300fb341f29dec9166022a25e07f36f0).

Comment: Another approach would be not to use `{{input}}` helper. `<input value={{model.name}}>` would also give one-way binding without adding that much complexity. There isn't any `onenter` event but you could use `onkeyup` instead and filter for enter events in your action.

Answer (score 0):

{{input type="text" value=model.name  oninput=(action 'sampleFunction' model.name)}}